# How to initialize a vector with elements between two point and step c++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, typedef

I'm going to initialize a vector that the elements are scaled uniformly between two numbers with known steps. something like this pseudo code.

```
typedef vector<double> a(startnumber, step, endnumber);
```

e.g.

```
vector<double> a(1, 1, 10); // a = {1, 2, ...., 10};
```

Is there any way to do it in c++?

Comment: If step is 1 you can do `vector<double> a(10); iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> createRange(T start, T end, T step)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    for (; start < end; start += step) {
        result.push_back(start);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Anything else is more complicated without really being better (e.g. something with `iota()` or `generate()`). This'll only work if `step` > 0. If you want it to work for negative steps, will have to switch on the sign to check `start > end` in that case instead.

Comment: There's an annoying potential rounding issue if `T = double`

Comment: I'was going to say it's good to make it as a template that you've just did :) thanks!

Comment: Consider calling result.reserve() for the expected size to avoid the overhead of resizing.  Also consider having the caller supply the std::vector to avoid having to copy.

Comment: @seand Sure for the reserve, but there won't be a copy... RVO.